# how to watermark a rendered PDF (on context) without repeating the image

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf-generation

I'm rendering a PDF file on my iPad using a graphics PDF context. The PDFs vary in size but may be up to 90 pages. I need a background image on each page but if I simply draw it the PDF file size will be way larger. Is there a way to kinda only add it once and 'share' it somehow across pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test where I repeated a background image behind each PDF page. Surprisingly, the file size increased by a single and constant amount, regardless of the number of pages with repeated backgrounds.

The verdict: The drawing to PDF context libraries are smarter than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF format specification enables you to re-use objects "by reference". You can re-use any object multiple times that is defined only once. Usually that happens with fonts, logos, background images, watermarks, ICC profiles, ....

Comment: But when I render an image on a pdf context it is just imagedata.. long since separated from the name...?

Comment: Does it reuse images by doing a checksum on the imagedata or something?

Comment: I was talking about the PDF **file**, as stored on **hardisk** or SD card. I do not know what happens if a PDF **renderer** has to display the pages. It may separately render each occurence of the image on each page and occupy the required **RAM** multiple times...

Comment: Hmm.. no way to reuse internal images by reference?

Comment: Are you talking about "internal images" of a PDF file stored on a harddisk? Then the answer is *"Yes, they can store an image object once inside the PDF and re-use it multiple times by reference."* -- Or are you taling about the RAM usage situation, where such a PDF is rendered and displayed by a PDF viewer? Then my answer is *"I don't know, but I guess it is up to the viewer. 'Intelligent' viewers may be able to re-use an image multiple times that is loaded/rendered into memory once... 'Stupid' oned may behave stupidly."*